# How to get all products in a parent category (first level) in opencart?

Tags: opencart

**How to get all products in a parent category (first level) in opencart?**

including all subcategories and their products

All products under a menu(category) including its subcategory products(children)

Answer (score 3):

Considering You have ID of current category stored in `$category_id`, You could try:

```php
$data = array(
    'filter_category_id'  => $category_id,
    'filter_sub_category' => true
);

$products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

Comment: What do You mean by *starting/final* level...?

Comment: primary category. ie, if 3 catergores a, b, c. and a h'v another category a1,a2,a3.. and be have b1,b2.. similarly c. and a1 have another subcategory,a1-1,a1-2,a1-2.... similarly a2 . what i need is get all products on clicking a. ie product of a1,a2...,a1-1,a1-2.. a2-1...